# Accessing to the AST of a function in Julia

Tags: julia

In Julia, it is possible to *view* the AST of a user defined function:

```
julia> myFunc(x) = 5*x+3
myFunc (generic function with 1 method)

julia> tmp = dump(quote myFunc end)
Expr 
  head: Symbol block
  args: Array(Any,(2,))
    1: Expr 
      head: Symbol line
      args: Array(Any,(2,))
        1: Int64 1
        2: Symbol none
      typ: Any
    2: Symbol myFunc
  typ: Any
```

Which is the AST I am interested in. However, the variable tmp doesn't contain the `Expr` representing the syntactic tree I am expecting:

```
julia> tmp

julia> typeof(tmp)
Nothing (constructor with 1 method)
```

Is there another way to get this `Expr`? (the one that is displayed when running `dump(quote myFunc end)` )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access the AST of a function, because a function is a a collection of methods (that might be implemented differently) in Julia. If it suits your needs you should use the documented `code_typed` function, where you specify the types of the arguments to select the right method. There are also some hints in [Access the AST for generic functions in Julia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14124456/access-the-ast-for-generic-functions-in-julia?rq=1), but that is not documented functionality, so it might change without warning.

Comment: OK, thanks for clarifying that. I'll write a macro that keeps the source of the functions in the same time it creates it. That will do for my project (the one with the derivatives, I think I'll merge it with calculus.jl soon).

Answer (score 4):

`dump` does not give you the result; it is just a way of printing the value. (As you saw, it prints as a side-effect and returns a `nothing`.)

What you gave `dump` was an AST containing the *name* of your function, not the function itself. `dump` is not printing out a representation of your function: it is saying it has a block of one line containing the symbol `myFunc`.

If you want the AST, you should run `code_typed(myFunc,(Any,))` or `code_lowered(myFunc,(Any,))`. For other functions, you will need different and/or more specific type signatures as the second argument.

If you are only planning to call `myFunc` with `Int`s or `Float64`s or whatever, use that instead of `Any` -- it will make a difference to `code_typed`'s output, since the type inference will change.

I wrote a blog post documenting the `code_typed`/`code_lowered` set of functions: http://blog.leahhanson.us/julia-introspects.html
(I also spend time in that post looking at their output, the `Expr` type and explaining it's structure.)

The [Metaprogramming section](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.2/manual/metaprogramming/) of the official manual will probably be useful to you in working with ASTs, if you haven't already read it.

Answer (score 0):

[ivarne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/112019/ivarne) is correct, you can't access the AST of a function *after* Julia evaluated it.  Like the sketch parrot, it has "joined the bleedin' choir invisible".  But what if you accessed it *before* julia evaluates it?

```
julia> tmp = :(myFunc(x) = 5x+3)
:(myFunc(x) = begin
          #= REPL[1]:1 =#
          5x + 3
      end)

julia> eval(tmp)
myFunc (generic function with 1 method)
```

Because you short-circuited julia's [order of evaluation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/devdocs/eval/), you can keep a reference to the desired AST.  The downside is that you need to then [`eval`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.MainInclude.eval) your function before you can use it.

(and yes, this is basically what julia [macros](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/metaprogramming/#man-macros) do but your specific use case might not need a macro)